# What are the steps of Locally linear Embedding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I've been using sklearn's library for some time, but now I am interested in what happens under the hood so that I can code it from scratch. Is there a website where I can find a pseudocode or Python code for LLE's?

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow, but lucky for you each sklearn page has a handy link to the source code right at the top of the page! If you go to the [sklearn lle page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding.html) and click the `[source]` link at the top you can see [exactly what's coded under the hood](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/manifold/_locally_linear.py#L521)

Comment: You can also see the pseudocode/steps in the [sklearn LLE user guide page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#locally-linear-embedding)